# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 Using Mongodb with react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am new to the MongoDB and React and I was trying to make my first mern app using
https://www.mongodb.com/languages/mern-stack-tutorial
Wrote everything as it is but keep getting an error saying : Cannot GET /record/ in the browser. not sure what is causing the error so I created an Atlas database with the name employees and collection records but kept getting the error

```
//record.js
const express = require("express");
const recordRoutes = express.Router();
const dbo = require("../db/conn");
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
recordRoutes.route("/record").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  db_connect
    .collection("records")
    .find({})
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(result);
    });
});
recordRoutes.route("/record/:id").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId( req.params.id )};
  db_connect
      .collection("records")
      .findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result);
      });
});
recordRoutes.route("/record/add").post(function (req, response) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myobj = {
    name: req.body.name,
    position: req.body.position,
    level: req.body.level,
  };
  db_connect.collection("records").insertOne(myobj, function (err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    response.json(res);
  });
});
recordRoutes.route("/update/:id").post(function (req, response) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();  
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId( req.params.id )};  
  let newvalues = {    
    $set: {      
      name: req.body.name,     
      position: req.body.position,      
      level: req.body.level,    
  },  
};
recordRoutes.route("/:id").delete((req, response) => {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb();
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId( req.params.id )};
  db_connect.collection("records").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document deleted");
    response.json(obj);
  });
});
module.exports = recordRoutes  } )
```

Comment: You have to be more specific with your question. There could be a lot of reasons causing your problem. It could be a failed API call, could be wrong password in your URI. What is the status code in console?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your question title. Could you please check if your directory path are the same as that in the tutorial?

Comment: I have missed the root folder NEW FOLDER which contains the mern folder by mistake...  the mern folder containing both the server and client is my root folder could that be the case

Comment: Glad you found the problem.